# How to pass the parameters in a model class construct method in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

Normally when you load a model in opencart, you will do the following:

```
$this->load->model('example');
// calling the method inside the model
$this->model_example->method();
```

However, right now I'm having a model that has a construct function, like this:

```
public function __construct( $filepath, $timezone, $priority, $registry){
  // code...
}
```

As you can see, I need to load the model with all the parameters that are required in the construct function, so how do I load my model in this case?

Comment: is this codeigniter ?

Comment: @Demonyowh No, it's opencart, but their syntax is very similar

Answer (score 1):

What you can do it calling the parent constructor, and making the other parameters optional. The only problem is that you still wouldn't use that new parameters because the load function doesn't allow that without changing the loader.

**Example contructor**

```
public function __construct( $registry, $filepath='', $timezone='', $priority='' ) {
  parent::__construct($registry);

  // Your code here
}
```

**Model function in loader**

```
public function model($model) {
    $file = DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/' . $model . '.php';
    $class = 'Model' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $model);

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);

        $this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $file . '!');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct requires a registry variable. you can handle that like this

```
class ControllerMyClass extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        global $registry;
        parent::__construct($registry);

        $this->load->model('example');
        // calling the method inside the model
        $this->model_example->method();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.